# Intuition of the fractional linear transformation $f(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given fractional linear transformation 
$$f(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$$ $a\in B_1(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$, we see that $f$ is a bijection from the unit disk onto itself.

How can I understand intuitively what this mapping looks like, I tried to plug a few points, but I can not quite get the big picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most helpful thing to notice is that $a$ maps to $0$. Then in order to map the unit circle to itself, you have to move something else to infinity (an affine transformation obviously moves all circles). It turns out that point is $1/\bar{a}$, as you no doubt have found already.

We can say a bit more: since Möbius transforms map circles to circles (including lines), the line through $0$ and $a$ is mapped to itself: if $k$ is real,
$$ \frac{ka-a}{1-\bar{a}ak} = \frac{k-1}{1-k\lvert a \rvert^2}a. $$
We also know that circles through $1/\bar{a}$ become straight lines in the plane, and in particular, circles through $a$ and $1/\bar{a}$ become lines through zero. (Such circles must also cut the unit circle orthogonally, since orthogonality is preserved by Möbius transformations.)

---

I don't remember if this particular transformation is discussed explicitly, but Tristan Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis* has a good chapter on Möbius transformations, with lots of pictures.